# Using single linked lists, how to swap nodes in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Currently, I've been trying to rearrange a linked list based on my main function switch(myList,index).

```
def createList(plist):
    linkedList = None
    # goes backwards, adding each element to the beginning
    # of the list.  
    for index in range(len(plist)-1, -1, -1):
        linkedList = insertValueHead(linkedList, plist[index])
    return linkedList

def insertValueHead(linkedList, value):
    newnode = {}
    newnode["data"] = value
    #set the next pointer of this new node to the head of the list, linkedList
    #newnode is now the head of the list 
    newnode["next"] = linkedList
    return newnode

def listString(linkedList):
   ptr = linkedList
   str1 = ''
   while ptr != None:
     str1 += str(ptr['data'])
     ptr = ptr['next']
     if ptr != None:
      str1 += "->"
  str1 = str1
  return str1

def switch(j, i):
   head = j
   currentItem = j[0]     # The head again
   prevItem = 1       # The item that links to tempItem
   for x in range(i):    # Find the item to swap
        prevItem = currentItem
        currentItem = currentItem['next']
        currentItem = currentItem['next']
        temp = currentItem['next']
        currentItem['next'] = head['next']
        head['next'] = prevItem['next']
        prevItem['next'] = temp

def testSwitch():
    #test code to ensure that switch() is working correctly.
    myList = createList([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60])
    print "The initial list", listString(myList)
    myList = switch(myList, 2)
    print "Switching the 1 and the 2.  Resulting list is ", listString(myList)

testSwitch()
```

This should yield a list with swapped elements. However, when I run it this is the output:

```
The initial list 10->20->30->40->50->60
Switching the 1 and the 2.  Resulting list is
```

This is then followed by the error:

```
    currentItem = currentItem['next']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't seem to figure it out...

Comment: What's the use of str1 = str1 ?

Comment: Can you not use a class based list? It would really simplify this problem.

Comment: Not sure what a class based list is. Just learning how to do linked lists in python without using the built in functions.

Comment: This is clearly not the actual code that's running; your `for` loop in `switch` isn't lined up with the indention of the code before it; and there's no way that `currentItem = j[0]` can succeed when you've passed in `myList` as `j`, since your "list nodes" don't have `0` keys, they have only `'next'` and `'data'` keys.

Comment: The indentation was fixed and it now gives the error TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str. So more problems it seems?

Answer (score 2):

The simply-linked list is not a very useful construct, if you need to support switch operation. On a doubly linked list, if the nodes have the pointers forward and backward, then it is very easy, but on singly linked list you need to scan the list at least once. Also, your code is so messy that no one can really debug it. Thus

- use class-based lists instead having items of a Node subclass, say.
- for `switch` operation you seriously want to have doubly linked list.
  Maybe use the linux linked list convention, where the ends are a list node too

Something like

```
 class Node(object):
     prev = None
     next = None

 class List(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.head = self
         self.tail = self
         self.prev = self
         self.next = self
         self.nil = self

     def insert_head(self, node):
         node.next = self.head.next
         self.head.next.prev = node
         node.prev = self.head
         self.head.next = node

     def __iter__(self):
         current = self.head.next
         while current != self.nil:
             yield current
             current = current.next

     def __str__(self):  # the "list_string" op
         items = []
         return ' -> '.join(map(str, self))

 class TestNode(Node):
     def __init__(self, value):
         self.value = value

     def __repr__(self):
         return repr(self.value)

list = List()
list.insert_head(TestNode('a'))
list.insert_head(TestNode('b'))
print(list)
```

Answer (score -2):

Your indentation isn't proper, that's why you are getting the issue.

```
def switch(j, i):
    head = j
    currentItem = j[0]     # The head again
    prevItem = 1       # The item that links to tempItem
    for x in range(i):    # Find the item to swap
        prevItem = currentItem
        currentItem = currentItem['next']
        currentItem = currentItem['next']
        temp = currentItem['next']
        currentItem['next'] = head['next']
        head['next'] = prevItem['next']
        prevItem['next'] = temp
```

Give an indent of four spaces inside a function or a loop. You can't assign j[0] to current item as it's a dict.

Comment: Invalid indentation produces a `SyntaxError`. OP has copied the code wrong, or thinks different code is running from what is actually running.

Comment: here j is dict with keys 'data' and 'next', you cannot assign j[0] to currentItem. You're trying to use a dict as a list @Jonathan

Comment: Now I'm getting a different error "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str". I've gone through the code but to no avail...